# If + Had PP ---> would be, is it a formal construction?

Tags: conditional-constructions

Is it correct to use **would be** rather than *would have been* in this construction:  *If + had pp  ---> would be* ?

Because I do not remember seeing that usage in grammar books.

Is that ok to use this construction in formal or academic writing ?

Thank you

[image]

Comment: You once said you didn't know what "accepting" an answer meant. Please look at the link on SE Meta to *see* how to accept answers. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: It is simple:  If {x} had happened,  something *would have been* possible **in the past**, or something *would be* possible **now**.  If I had remembered my wallet, I would have been able to buy lunch yesterday.  If I had remembered my wallet, I would be able to buy lunch now. The time of the situation-contrary-to-fact is ambiguous or ambivalent.  It never happened.

Comment: I have learned from my text books that would be is only used when we speak in the past simple like in: If I remembered my wallet  I would be able to buy lunch yesterday. They call it the second conditional case and never ever use had+pp with would be. So it is not that simple for me : )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**would be** and **would have been** are used to refer to conditional states.

As in the cartoon, you use **would be** to refer to a state that would exist **now**, or to some **general truth**, if things had gone differently.

You use **would have been** to refer to a state that would have existed **at some time in the past** (and may still exist), if things had gone differently. Here is an example:

> If you'd started getting ready when I told you, we would have been on our way half an hour ago.

It is fine to use **would be** and **would have been** in formal and academic environments, however they are not interchangeable: you have to choose the right one for the context.

Here are two published examples that demonstrate the difference: the first is a general truth (would be) and the second is a past state (would have been).

> If each interaction took 15 minutes, there **would be** time for only 26 interactions — without any time for lunch. - *School Administration - Jane L. Sigford (2005)*
>
> The Bank Directors of those days were impressed with the conviction that their refusal to discount the paper sent in to them **would have been** highly detrimental, if not destructive, to the trade of the country - *Bank of England - John Cazenove (1832)*

You can indeed use **would be** after **If I had + PP**, as long as either the consequence is **still in effect**, or it is a **general truth**.

Comment: Thanks for the answer  but do you mean we should not use *would be* in academic or formal writings?

Comment: @GamalThomas, I have updated my answer: I hope that makes it clear.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I think I am who are not clear enough, my main question is it fine to use would be **in the if+ Had PP construction** because I do not see that in grammar books. Is that ok to use it with this construction in formal writing ? I will edit my question.

Comment: Search for mixed conditionals.

Comment: I have updated my answer again.

Comment: **bet** is an unusual verb in that many speakers avoid using the past tense form, **betted**, and use "bet" for both present and simple past. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=betted&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbetted%3B%2Cc0